# Size limitation of sqlite on iphone

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I'd like to use sqlite on iPhone.

Is there any size limitation in a sqlite file?

Otherwise, Is it depended on disk space of iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically limited by storage space. If you will have huge databases, you should place them in a location where they will not be backed up to iCloud.

Comment: I found that my iCound is occupied my test iPhone app over 400MB.  I have to manage it. Thank you!